# How do I make an iOS custom gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where you draw half a circle with your finger in order to do something. How would I make a custom gesture recognizer to track if a user makes half a circle with their finger on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSInteger level;
    CGPoint   oldPoint;
    CGPoint   newPoint;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"start");
    level = 0;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    newPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    oldPoint = newPoint;
    newPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (newPoint.y > oldPoint.y && newPoint.x < oldPoint.x && level==0) {
        level += 1;
    }

    if (newPoint.y > oldPoint.y && newPoint.x > oldPoint.x && level==1) {
        level += 1;
    }
    if (newPoint.y < oldPoint.y && newPoint.x > oldPoint.x && level==2) {
        level += 1;
    }
    if (newPoint.y < oldPoint.y && newPoint.x < oldPoint.x && level==3) {
        level += 1;
    }

    if (4 == level) {
        level = 0;
        NSLog(@"successs");
    }
}
```